# Set entry point on Visual Studio Command Prompt

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-line, sdl

I'm trying to compile a simple c++ program using SDL and OpenGL. The problem is that I don't want to do that using the VS normal project. I want to compile it using the VS command prompt. I'm using the following command line:

```
    C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Program> cl /EHsc /MDd main.cpp
```

and it is giving the following error:

```
    Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved

    main.cpp
    Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved

    /out:main.exe
    main.obj
    LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
    C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Program>
```

I know that the error only appears when including SDL.h but it won't help you...
So, what is the code to change the entry point and how would the entire compilation command line look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler where the header files are with `/I` and where the libraries are installed after `/link`.

I extracted the library to a sub folder called `SDL-1.2.15`. Then copied `SDL.dll` to the same folder as my `.cpp` file.

### build.cmd

```
cl ^
  /EHsc^
  /MDd^
  /ISDL-1.2.15/include^
  main.cpp^
  /link^
  SDL-1.2.15/lib/x86/SDL.lib^
  SDL-1.2.15/lib/x86/SDLmain.lib^
  /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS^
  /NODEFAULTLIB:msvcrt.lib
```

I used the following page as a guide: http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php